# OOP Java Design Pattern for the following Scenario

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have the following scenario I'm struggling to come up with an elegant solution for...

1. I have an endpoint that is subscribed to a pub-sub topic, this particular pub-sub topic has 10 different type of notifications/messages it can read.

The following is the interface

```
public interface Handler {
    void handle(String msg);
}
```

The following is an Event Handler

```
public class TeamMemberHandler implements Handler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String msg) {

    }
}
```

The following is the pubsub listener class, where I want to move away from having 10 different switch cases for each event.

```
public class PubSubListener {

    // garbage quick example


    @PostMapping("/pubsublistener")
    private String pubsublistener(@RequestBody String msg) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new Gson.fromJson(msg, HashMap.class);

        String event = (String)map.get("rootElement");

        // want to move away from this
        switch(event){
            case "1":
                break;
            .
            .
            .

            case "10":
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to do something along the following... where I have a map of every single event type in String, and the Handler associated with it.

However, it is not possible to do handler.handle() in the below code. How can I go about achieving this?

```
        Map<String, Class<? extends Handler>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
        handlers.put("TeamMemberEvent",  TeamMemberHandler.class);
        handlers.put("OtherTypeOfEvent", OtherTypeOfHandler.class);

        Class<? extends Handler> handler = handlers.get(event);
        handler.handle(msg);
```

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand a design pattern.  They are generally how one discovers that a language is repetitively used to solve a larger problem than the language's built-in facilities provide.

In your case, you want to use a `Map` which is a built-in facility of the language, within the `java.util` package.  Assuming you have a `Map` of type `<String, ? extends Handler>` you can get the `? extends Handler` by looking up the value with the `String`.  An example of this might look like:

```
@PostMapping("/pubsublistener")
private String pubsublistener(@RequestBody String msg) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new Gson.fromJson(msg, HashMap.class);

    String event = (String)map.get("rootElement");
    Handler handler = handlers.get(event);
    handler.handle(event);
}
```

Note that before you use this approach, you need to populate the `Map` with your handlers and the strings that will be used to look them up.  This is done with the `.put(key, value)` method of the `Map` which, in your case, would take a string as the key and a handler as the value.

Comment: How would I go about populating this map correctly? It would be something along the lines of.... map.put(event, class???), but in this scenario if I have OtherTypeOfHandler.java, what would the value be in this case for the map.

Comment: @Skrytz If it is possible to put all the desired values into the map at once, I suggest putting them into the Map before it is used.  Generally we expect some setup code at the beginning of a program; before it starts handling requests.  If the Map's contents change over time, you'll have to decide what input will trigger what goes into the Map, and how to match the two together.

Answer (score 0):

1st option - If the handler does not take any parameters in the constructor, you can do the following:

```java
private final Map<String, Supplier<Handler>> handlersByEvent = Map.of(
    "1", TeamMemberHandler::new,
    "2", OtherTypeOfHandler::new
);
```

then at `::pubsublistener`:

```java
...
Supplier<Handler> handlerBuilder = handlersByEvent.get(map.get("rootElement"));
Handler handler = handlerBuilder.get();
handler.handle(msg);
```

---

2nd option - Use a bunch of methods instead of classes for the handlers:

```java
private final Map<String, Consumer<String>> handlersByEvent = Map.of(
    "1", this::handleTeamMemberMethod,
    "2", this::handleOtherTypeOfMethod
);
```

then at `::pubsublistener`:

```
...
Consumer<String> handler = handlersByEvent.get(map.get("rootElement"));
handler.accept(msg);
```

---

There are probably other, even better, approaches...